# why i am unable to acces the instance properties / properties defined inside the constructor into static method

Tags: javascript, static-methods

```
class Person{
  constructor(firstname,lastname){
    this.firstname=firstname
    this.lastname = lastname
  }

  static bio(){
    return `${this.firstname}`
  }

}

personOne = new Person('Deepak','Kumar')
console.log(Person.bio())
```

**I am trying to access the properties I have defined inside the constructor inside the
static method but I am getting undefined. hiw to access the properties inside the static method .. why I am unable to access it please explain the concept behind this.**

Comment: You can not use `this.firstname` inside your static function. Since it is static it would not know the instance.. Remove the `static` and call `personOne.bio()` instead

Comment: Why is `bio` static here?

Comment: Then you will have to pass an instance in. You are misunderstanding the difference between static and regular methods on objects - static methods just _don't know about any instances of the object _. They're just like regular `function`s only defined on a class definition. They are not instances of said class. They have no `this`, really.

Comment: ya i got your point  i passed the instance and it worked .. yes I actually misunderstood the concept thanks bro .. new to javascript getting difficult to understand  @somethinghere

Comment: static will refer to the class, not an instance of class. Just renember it.

Answer (score 0):

A static method is associate to the Class not on the Object create by the class.

```js
class Toy{

        static ToyCollection = [];

        constructor(color,description){
            this.color = color;
            this.description = description;
            
            Toy.ToyCollection.push(this);
        }

        static redToy(){
            return new Toy('red','Red toy');
        }

        static BlueToy(){
            return new Toy('red','Blue toy');
        }

        static greenToy(){
            return new Toy('green','Green toy');
        }

        static Historique(){
            this.ToyCollection.forEach(toy => {
                console.log(toy);
            });
        }
        
        static ToyIDInformation(id){
            return this.ToyCollection[id];
        }
        
        ToyInformation(){
            console.log('Toy color : '+this.color);
            console.log('Toy Description : '+this.description);
        }
    }

    let purpleToy = new Toy('purple','Custom toy')

    Toy.Historique();
    console.log('------------------')
    let redToy = Toy.redToy();

    Toy.Historique();

    console.log('-------------')
    console.log('You can')
    console.log('-------------')
    purpleToy.ToyInformation();

    console.log('-------------')
    console.log('But you cant')
    console.log('-------------')
    try{
      purpleToy.Historique();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    purpleToy.Historique();
    console.log('-------------')
    console.log('neither')
    console.log('-------------')
    try{
      Toy.ToyInformation();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
```

Comment: while returning static method you have written return  new whats the reason behind writing return new . @WolfCode

Comment: Sry the late replay ( lunch time ) @Deepak_Kumar The static is more often for `CollectionObject` and Fast casting new class object , As you can see here , the `static` methode can return a `new Toy ` ( without setting the proprety as optionnel or value pre-define ).

Comment: Interesting, I never knew that the `this` in a `static` is actually the class object itself. Cool. Learn something new every day.

Comment: @WolfCode so u have used "this" here inside the static . Is It referring to class name Toy here ...????

Comment: @WolfCode and I still don't understand why the "return new" ..new keyword is basically used to create an object from a constructor function .. there are some other things that are also done by new. it also creates an empty object, sets the prototype property but why here .. what is here new keyword is doing ..!!

Comment: In this case, ‘this’ refers to the class object itself, not an instance of it.